# Incomplete execution of stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I have a stored procedure with a while inside which receives 2 parameters for the condition of the while. I make it to work like a for. If I executed it from SQL it works perfectly, but If I call it from PHP, the while doesn't respect the condition and suddenly ends.

The while insert an iterator number in each row like

```
1,a,b
2,a,b
3,a,b
```

etc. If I set the iterations from 1 to 1000 the loop stop without a reason in different interaction in every execution of the SP.

I have a try/catch and I can't detect the error.

I'm sure all the parameters are right.

Can someone help me to detect why the stored procedure can't end correctly?

I'm using PDO to access to SQL Server.

Store Procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_AddSealsFromPurchase]
@initialFolio int,
@finalFolio int,
@userDelivery_ID varchar(50),
@userReceives_ID varchar(50),
@color nvarchar(10),
@supplier_ID int,
@requisition_ID int,
@office_ID int,
@reference nvarchar(50)
as
begin
declare @now datetime;
set @now = getdate();
    while @initialFolio<=@finalFolio Begin
    begin try
        INSERT into Seals (SealNo,SealType,Color,Supplier_ID,[Source],Office_ID,Requisition_ID,Reference)
        Values (@initialFolio,1,@color,@supplier_ID,1,@office_ID,@requisition_ID,@reference)
        INSERT INTO StatusSeal(Seal_ID,Status_ID,UserDelivery_ID,UserReceives_ID,StatusSeal_Date,UserDeliveryType,UserReceivesType)
        Values(@@Identity,1,@userDelivery_ID,@userReceives_ID,@now,1,1)
        set @initialFolio = @initialFolio +1;
        end try
begin catch
        set @initialFolio = @initialFolio +1;
end catch  
    end
end
```

PHP:

```
function AddSealsFromPurchase($Data){
    session_start();
    $cnx=$this->connectSqlSrv();
    $sth=$cnx->prepare("Exec sp_AddSealsFromPurchase ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
    $sth->bindParam(1, $Data["InitialFolio"]);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $Data["FinalFolio"]);
    $sth->bindParam(3, $Data["UserDelivery"]);
    $sth->bindParam(4, $_SESSION['SESSINFOSEAL']['User_Usr']);
    $sth->bindParam(5, $Data["Color"]);
    $sth->bindParam(6, $Data["Supplier_ID"]);
    $sth->bindParam(7,  $Data["Requisition_ID"]);
    $sth->bindParam(8, $_SESSION['SESSINFOSEAL']['Ofice_ID']);
    $sth->bindParam(9, $Data["Reference"]);
    session_write_close();
    $retval=$this->ExecuteNoQuery($sth);
    return json_encode($retval);
  }

public function connectSqlSrv(){
        try{
            $dbCnx = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$this->server;Database=$this->db", $this->usr, $this->psw);
            $dbCnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $dbCnx;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
            die();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function ExecuteNoQuery($sth)
    {
        $r=array('data'=>false,
        'error'=>false,
        'r'=>'');
        try {
            $sth->execute();
            if ($r['r'] = $sth->rowCount()) {
                $r['data'] = true;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $r['error']=true;
            $r['r'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $r;
    }
```

Comment: If it's working from SQL Server then the SP is correct. Could you please use SQL Server Profiler to verify the parameter values passed to the SP while running through your PHP page?

Comment: SQL Profiler shows everything fine al the parameters are correct

Comment: I extracted the query and executed it from SQL and it works perfectly a don't know the the hell is going on. PDO have a limit or something that can truncate the execution?